# Hide group with no child - ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, expandablelistview

I want to hide the whole group from `ExpandableListView` if it has no child(s). I've tried to use this in the `public View getGroupView`:

```
if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) == 0) {
    convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    lblListHeader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
    convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lblListHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

But that is not working I still see the indicator (the text is removed) and a empty space.

Also I've tried this:

```
if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) == 0) {
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_layout, null);
}
```

That's working but when I try to open another group I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Is it possible to hide group(s) from `ExpandableListView` if it has no child(s)?

Comment: How is the `ExpandableListViewAdapter` being set? You may have to alter the data going into the `Adapter` in order to have your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the datamodel in the adapter so that it allows removal and then once you have it removed you set invoke notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.